# Ember.Data JSON not being pushed into store

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I am having trouble getting my API json results to be pushed into the Ember Data object model array. I was previously using getJSON on my route however I now need to be able to filter the data on multiple properties and Ember Data provides built in methods for that...if I could get it work that is. I'm pretty new to this so I am probably missing something terribly obvious. Please let me know if I am missing any code to assist. When I look at the promises, it shows them fulfilled when pulling the data from the API but then it rejects when trying to query the local data store for records (shows null) which I believe means my data isn't getting added to the store in the first place. I would provide a JSBin but our api uses CORS and I can't get the JSbin origin to authenticate.

On the route I have tried the following. Both throw different errors:

```
return this.store.find('restaurant');
//returns error: Error while processing route: casualdining  
//Array.prototype.map: 'this' is null or undefined.

return DineSection.Restaurant.find();
//Error while processing route: casualdining 
//Object doesn't support property or method 'find'
```

The Application Code:

```
DineSection = Ember.Application.create({
      rootElement: "#dinesection-app"  
  });

DineSection.Router.map(function () {         
      this.resource("casualdining");  
      this.resource("restaurant", { path: "/:id" });

  });

DineSection.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: 'https://api.lakecountyfl.gov',
        namespace: 'api/TourismListings',
        pathForType: function (type) {              
            return "GetRestaurants";   
        }
  });

DineSection.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
     adapter: 'DineSection.ApplicationAdapter'
  });

//SERIALIZE OUR JSON DATA FROM THE API into something ember data can use 
  DineSection.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      normalizePayload: function (type, payload) {
          return { restaurant: payload }
      }
  });

DineSection.Restaurant = DS.Model.extend({       
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      address: DS.attr('string'),
      city: DS.attr('string'),
      zip: DS.attr('string'),
      phone: DS.attr('string'),
      website: DS.attr('string'),
      facebook: DS.attr('string'),
      flickr: DS.attr('string'),
      hasphoto: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
      outdoordining: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
      breakfastprice: DS.attr('string'),
      lunchprice: DS.attr('string'),
      dinnerprice: DS.attr('string'),
      description: DS.attr('string'),
      primarycategoryname: DS.attr('string'),
      primarycategoryslug: DS.attr('string'),
      primarysubcategoryname: DS.attr('string'),
      primarysubcategoryslug: DS.attr('string'),         
      foodtype: DS.attr('string'),
      foodtypeid: DS.attr('number'),        
      ranking: DS.attr('number'),
      region1: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
      region2: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
      region3: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
      region4: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }) 
  });

DineSection.CasualdiningRoute = Ember.Route.extend({         
     model: function () {          
         //return Ember.$.getJSON("https://devapi.lakecountyfl.gov/api/TourismListings/GetRestaurants");               
         return this.store.find('restaurant');
         //return DineSection.Restaurant.find();
     }
 });
```

My JSON response looks like this (abbreviated to two records for simplicity):

```
[{
"$id": "1",
"id": 1212,
"name": "Al's Landing",
"address": "111 W. Ruby St.",
"city": "Tavares",
"zip": "32778",
"phone": "352-555-8585",
"website": "http://www.alslanding.com",
"facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/ALS-landing/110275062350544",
"flickr": null,
"hasphoto": true,
"outdoordining": true,
"breakfastprice": "N/A",
"lunchprice": "$10-$20",
"dinnerprice": "$10-$20",
"description": "A casual dining atmosphere with an indoor/ outdoor bar and plenty of outdoor lakefront seating.",
"primarycategoryname": "Dining",
"primarycategoryslug": "dining",
"primarysubcategoryname": "Casual Dining",
"primarysubcategoryslug": "casualdining",
"foodtype": "American",
"foodtypeid": 13,
"ranking": 3,
"region1": false,
"region2": false,
"region3": true,
"region4": false  
},
{
"$id": "2",
"id": 1026,
"name": "#1 Wok",
"address": "1080 E. Highway 50",
"city": "Clermont",
"zip": "34711",
"phone": "352-555-2346",
"website": "",
"facebook": "",
"flickr": "",
"hasphoto": false,
"outdoordining": false,
"breakfastprice": "N/A",
"lunchprice": "Less than $10",
"dinnerprice": "Less than $10",
"description": "",
"primarycategoryname": "Dining",
"primarycategoryslug": "dining",
"primarysubcategoryname": "Casual Dining",
"primarysubcategoryslug": "casualdining",
"foodtype": "Asian",
"foodtypeid": 1,
"ranking": 1,
"region1": false,
"region2": false,
"region3": false,
"region4": true
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a 'root' key in your JSON like follows:
  [ restaurants: {